# JAVA Datasource

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic

I am trying to use a datasource that I set up on my weblogic server.
datasource JNDI name = thinOracleDataSource

in my code I have the following

```
public class DAOBean implements java.io.Serializable {
private Connection conn;
public void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException,
SQLException, NamingException {
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
// Lookup using JNDI name.
DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("thinOracleDataSource");
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

}

But I get this error

```
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /thinOracleDataSource in /app/webapp/PreAssignment2/24911485.; remaining name '/thinOracleDataSource'
```

am I looking the JNDI name in the right way? or am I missing something? Thanks for any help!!

EDIT:
This is the jndi tree that I can get from the weblogic console 
[image]

Comment: Could you please paste your datasource definition?

Comment: Can you please explain what the definition is or help me in how I can find it? I am very new to this

Comment: You wrote - `I am trying to use a datasource that I set up on my weblogic server.` Paste the exact set up of your datasource. I have also not used WebLogic. I am just trying to help.

Comment: Though I am not really sure of what you need this for. but sure mate

jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:10002:ell

and my username and password. I tested the connection and I got that's its working. It's only that I can't look it up from my java code

Comment: Try to look at the weblogic log file. There should be a line for the datasource. Something like this: `[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1315572938610> <BEA-001174> <Creating Data Source named xyzDataSource, JNDI Name = weblogic.xyzDataSource>`

Comment: I can only access the web page of weblogic. I don't think I can do that. Can I ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try naming your datasource `jdbc/thisOracleDataSource` in Weblogic and reference it as:

```
DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/thinOracleDataSource");
```

Also, make sure the datasource is "targeted" to your weblogic Java server. All of this can be done in the Weblogic admin console.

Comment: Thanks. This solved it. It wasn't "targeted". 
For those who may have similar problem. You should go to Weblogic console >> sevices >> datasources >> choose your datasource >> targets >> choose your server 
I use weblogic 12c so things will differe in different versions.

Thanks again GriffeyDog!

Answer (score 1):

Your JNDI key should look like approximately `"java:comp/env/jdbc/thinOracleDataSource"`. 
You can verify it by using Weblogic console that allows access (and probably search) in JNDI. So, you can check this manually before writing the code.

Comment: +1, but do you know if WebLogic prefixes like Tomcat with "java:comp/env/"?. I am just curious.

Comment: Please have a look at the jndi tree. I couldn't find what I am looking for in there. Any suggestions ?